# Limit rsync to available space on destination

Tags: rsync, archiving

I have a directory, `/data/snapshots`, which I'd like to archive to an external drive mounted at `/mnt`.  The external is 2tb, `/data/snapshots` is much more.

If I:

```
rysnc -av /data/snapshot /mnt
```

Then the command fails once the external is full.  The problem then is I have no way to continue with the `rsync` once a new empty drive is mounted.

Currently it seems I have two options:

- generate a list of 2tb worth of files and then use rsync to iterate those files.  This seems needlessly cumbersome/error prone.
- instead use:
  `rsync --remove-source-files -av /data/snapshot /mnt`

Hopefully this is a solved problem and someone can point me to a solution.

edit:  To simply the request, what I would wish is a `--quantity 1.9tb` option within rsync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about trying this :

1. Use **du** to get a list of all the files and how much disk space used
2. Split this **filelist.txt** into smaller lists (**list1.txt**,
   **list2.txt**, etc), each adding up to 2TB
3. run **rsync --files-from** for each list, after swapping in an empty
   2TB drive

Comment: That's what I started doing, then I hit on a slightly simpler mechanism:  for files in directory; do rsync --remove-from-source files /destination/location ; if "1" == "$?" ; then break ; fi ; done ... this way each directory is removed when it's archived and when the drive fills up I swap the external and run it again.

Comment: Ah, did not know you wanted to move not copy, but your one-liner is a good to file away...might need it one day :)

Comment: I was going to copy then remove, but realized rsync could do that transaction for me.